# download open street maps' tiles.png

Tags: react-native, openstreetmap, react-native-maps

I'm trying to use offline open street map in a react native application, for that reason, and according to  [react native maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=react%20native%20maps&oq=react%20native%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j69i65.3229j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I need to store the tiles in a specific format :

> The path template of the locally stored tiles. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
>       
> For example, /storage/emulated/0/mytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

I tried to download the tiles using tiles [servers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers), however, I find out that It will take a lot of time (it is almost impossible) 
I also looked at the proposed [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) to download tiles, however, I don't know the files extension and I don't know if I could convert one of them to png, therefore, I wonder I there is an **opensource/free** way to do that

I find also, [this](http://allmapsoft.com/openstreetmap/) software but I can only use it up to zoom=13, otherwise its not for free.

Answer (score 4):

Bulk downloads are usually forbidden. See the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). Quoting the important parts:

> OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not.
>
> Bulk downloading is strongly discouraged. Do not download tiles unnecessarily.
>
> **In particular, downloading an area of over 250 tiles at zoom level 13 or higher for offline or later usage is forbidden.** These tiles are generally not available (cached) on the server in advance, and have to be rendered specifically for those requests, putting an unjustified burden on the available resources.

You can [render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) your own *raster* tiles by installing a rendering software such as [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill) or by [installing your own tile-server](https://switch2osm.org/). Alternatively take a look at [Commercial OSM software and services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services).

Alternatively switch to [*vector* tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). Obtaining raw OSM data is rather easy. Vector tiles allow you to render tiles on your device on the fly.

Comment: so there is no way to have an offline map, based on either google maps or OSM for react native apps !!!!

Comment: That's not correct. There are various ways for obtaining offline tiles. However there is no simple download link for mass-downloading free offline tiles because it costs a lot of resources to generate and distribute them.